# Dart RegExp, Why does this throw a FormatException

Tags: regex, dart

I'm not clear on why this is throwing a FormatException:

```
void main(){
  RegExp cssColorMatch = new RegExp(r'^#([0-9a-fA-F]{3}{1,2}$)');
  print(cssColorMatch.hasMatch('#F56'));
}
```

Comment: You can check your RegExp syntax using, e.g., http://regex101.com/r/wU7kG7 - it will tell you which part is the invalid syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do `{3}{1,2}`. But you can do:

```
RegExp cssColorMatch = new RegExp(r'^\#((?:[0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2})$');
```

which still does not match Hex colors correctly.

Comment: new RegExp(r'^#(([0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2})$') works for my use cases ,thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to specify **multiple** *range quantifiers* back to back which causes an exception error. You need to end your capturing group around your first range quantifier and place the following range quantifier outside of the capturing group if you want to use it this way.

```
RegExp re = new RegExp(r"#([0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2}");
```

Since you are using [hasMatch](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.RegExp#id_hasMatch), you can remove the start `^` and end `$` anchors since this function returns if the regular expression has a match in the string input and you really don't need `{1,2}` here either.

```
RegExp re = new RegExp(r"#([0-9a-fA-F]{3})");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your regex contains `{1,2}` at the last. There is no need to include this part.

Below regex would be enough,

```
RegExp cssColorMatch = new RegExp(r'^#([0-9a-fA-F]{3})$');
```